CSS Marquee Scrolling Effect Not Working as Expected
I'm trying to create a marquee scrolling effect from left to right using CSS, but I can't get it to work correctly. The content is supposed to scroll smoothly, but it doesn't behave as expected in my implementation.
My Goal
I want to create a smooth, continuous scrolling effect, similar to the classic <marquee> HTML tag but using modern CSS. The text and images should scroll from left to right across the screen in a loop.
The Problem
When I apply my CSS, the scrolling effect doesn't work smoothly, and sometimes the content doesn't loop as intended. I'm not sure if the issue lies with the @keyframes animation, the width settings, or something else.
What I've Tried
Here's the CSS and HTML I'm using:
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@900&display=swap');

.iso-marquee {
  padding: 1.4rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.iso-marquee--long {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  animation: iso-marquee 21s linear infinite;
  width: 2300px; /* Replace with your calculated total width */
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
  border-top: 1px solid #121212;
}

.marquee-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.TEES {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 85px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.branding {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes iso-marquee {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(-50%); }
}

/* Reduce motion for accessibility */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .iso-marquee {
    animation: none;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="iso-marquee-linkwrap">
  <div class="iso-marquee--long iso-marquee">
    <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
    <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
    <div class="branding">
      <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
      <span>MARK WITH</span>
      <span>EXCITISM</span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

What I Expect
I expect the above code to create a marquee effect similar to this one:
<style>
.marquee {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: clamp(4vw, 4rem, 8vw);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee--long {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #00112C;
  width: var(--tw);
  text-shadow: var(--tw) 0 currentColor,
               calc(var(--tw) * 2) 0 currentColor,
               calc(var(--tw) * 3) 0 currentColor,
               calc(var(--tw) * 4) 0 currentColor;

  will-change: transform;
  animation: marquee var(--ad) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .marquee div {
    animation: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="marquee" style="--tw: 40vw; --ad: 2.5s;">
  <span>Showreel</span>
</div>


I advise you to find examples on CodePen.com and learn from those. Good examples can teach you a lot.

You have the right idea, that essentially you have 'two copies' of the content and at the end of the animation time only half will have been moved across and the first half comes back - as they are identical we think it's continuous.
For this to work well you need certain things - removal of any spacing that the browser might insert by default (e.g. the 8px margin on body), enough copies of what you want to show to cover the viewport twice (we achieve this by using flex as you have done, but make sure the whole is at least 200vw wide).
I have removed some of the structure - it works fine if you just have one continuous set of what you want to show, doesn't necessarily need to be split in two.
I've made sure there is an even number of items.
They are justified space-around, not center. space-around puts even space between each item and half that space at each end.


<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@900&display=swap');
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .iso-marquee {
    padding: 1.4rem 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .iso-marquee--long {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    animation: iso-marquee 21s linear infinite;
    width: fit-content;
    /* Replace with your calculated total width */
    clear: both;
    rpadding: 0;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    border-top: 1px solid #121212;
    min-width: 200vw;
  }
  
  .marquee-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .TEES {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 85px;
    font-weight: 900;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  
  .branding {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  @keyframes iso-marquee {
    from {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
  }
  /* Reduce motion for accessibility */
  
  @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .iso-marquee {
      animation: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="iso-marquee-linkwrap">
  <div class="iso-marquee--long iso-marquee">
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-container">
      <img src="https://mrbeast.store/cdn/shop/files/photo_2023-06-29_02-49-55.jpg?height=85&v=1718170165" alt="" />
      <span class="TEES">TEES</span>
      <div class="branding">
        <span>MAKE YOUR</span>
        <span>MARK WITH</span>
        <span>EXCITISM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



